# WPF - Comboboxes doesn't render in a listview (only the first one)

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, combobox

I have a WPF MVVM Application and i have this problem...
I have a listview with a few textboxes and 2 comboboxes per column.
Everything renders just fine  except for the combos.
The combos populated and contain values and shows only the selected value 
of the first combos (in the first line of the listview).
I tried a little test and switched the comboboxes with a textboxed and had no problem so i guess it's something specific with the combos.
Please help me with this issue.

XAML :

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding NAPS_AgencyCodes}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentAgencyCode}"  MaxHeight="650" Margin="10 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderThickness="1" behave:ListBoxBehavior.ScrollOnNewItem="true">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Code" Width="80">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Code, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  MaxLength="4" FontSize="12" Margin="0 5 0 0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="300">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="12" Margin="0 5 0 0" MaxLength="100" Width="285" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="State" Width="250">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding States}" DisplayMemberPath="StateName" SelectedValuePath="ID"  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=StateCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" Margin="0 5 0 0" Width="235"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type Code" Width="250">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AgencyTypeCodes}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Code" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=AgencyTypeCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" Margin="0 5 0 0" Width="235"/>                                
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

View Model:

```
private NAPS_AgencyCode _agencyCode;
        private NAPS_AgencyCodeValidator _validator;
        public event Func<string> OnCodeChanged;
        public ObservableCollection<AIR_StateViewModel> States { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<NAPS_AgencyTypeCodeViewModel> AgencyTypeCodes { get; set; }        

        private int iCodeSerch;

        #endregion

        #region Ctor

        public NAPS_AgencyCodeViewModel(NAPS_AgencyCode agencyCode)
        {
            _agencyCode = agencyCode;
            _validator = new NAPS_AgencyCodeValidator(this);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string ID
        {
            get { return _agencyCode.ID;  }
            set { _agencyCode.ID = value; }
        }


        public string Code
        {
            get { return _agencyCode.Code; }
            set
            {
                if (_agencyCode.Code == value)
                    return;
                _agencyCode.Code = value;
                SetStatus();
                OnPropertyChanged("Code");              
            }
        }

        public string AgencyTypeCode
        {
            get { return _agencyCode.AgencyTypeCode; }
            set
            {
                if(_agencyCode.AgencyTypeCode == value)
                    return;
                _agencyCode.AgencyTypeCode = value;                
                SetStatus();
                OnPropertyChanged("AgencyTypeCode");                
            }
        }

        public int StateCode
        {
            get { return _agencyCode.StateCode; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _agencyCode.StateCode)
                    return;
                _agencyCode.StateCode = value;
                SetStatus();
                OnPropertyChanged("StateCode");
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return _agencyCode.Description; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _agencyCode.Description)
                    return;
                _agencyCode.Description = value;
                SetStatus();
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");                
            }
        }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return _agencyCode.IsValid; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _agencyCode.IsValid)
                    return;
                _agencyCode.IsValid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
            }
        }
```

And I have a Main View Model with

```
NAPS_AgencyCodes = Repository.NAPS_AgencyCodeRepository.NAPS_AgencyCodes
                            .ToObservableCollection<NAPS_AgencyCodeViewModel>();
```

Thank you so much !

Comment: Without seeing your actual code we can only assume things. This sounds like your defining your combos as static resources and then trying to reuse that resource several times. But Visuals can only have one parent. Mind to share your code with us?

Comment: Sorry, You right, I added some code.

Comment: Mmmmh... I don't see anything wrong with your code. Have you tried using a tool like Snoop to check what's being rendered? Check if the combox are actually there or not, if they're covered by something, and their Visibility, Width/Height, etc.

Comment: So is the posted code working or not.  does "Sorry, You right" mean it was a static resource and now it is working?  If so just delete the question.

Comment: No, it's not working... on load, all combos are populated and just the combos from the first line of the list view shows the selected value.

Comment: SelectedItem not SelectedValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K, I found my problem...
I populated the collections of the combos this way:
In the constractor I populated 2 collection only once into this.AgencyTypeCodes and this.AirStates and than I copied the date this way:

```
_NAPS_AgencyCodes = (from n in _dal.GetItems()
                                select new NAPS_AgencyCodeViewModel(n)
                        {
                            ObjectStatus = Status.NoChange,
                            AgencyTypeCodes = this.AgencyTypeCodes,
                            States =this.AirStates,                            
                        }
                      ).ToObservableCollection<NAPS_AgencyCodeViewModel>();
```

The solution is to give each combo new collection and this way thay wont point on each others collections like this:

```
_NAPS_AgencyCodes = (from n in _dal.GetItems()
                                select new NAPS_AgencyCodeViewModel(n)
                        {
                            ObjectStatus = Status.NoChange,
                            AgencyTypeCodes = new ObservableCollection<NAPS_AgencyTypeCodeViewModel>(this.AgencyTypeCodes),
                            States = new ObservableCollection<AIR_StateViewModel>(this.AirStates),                            
                        }
                      ).ToObservableCollection<NAPS_AgencyCodeViewModel>();
```